# Create and store different arrays in each object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

I'm new programming in JS and I'm designing an application to search for sites by county (it would be something like state) and municipality (Counties).

From the data I obtain through an API I get the following results.

[data from API](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0027B.png)

As you can see there are some counties that are repeated and what I am interested in is to assign the county in an object and within that object create an array with its municipalities.

At the moment I have removed the repeated counties, but I cannot put each object with its municipalities.

[API to array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Miiu9.png)

My code is the following basically what I do here is to remove the repeated data from the counties.

(variable **data** is the values from API picture 1)

```
for(let i=0; i< data.length; i++)
{
    let found = false;
    for (var j=0; j<array.length; j++) {
        if (data[i].nom_comarca == array[j].comarca) {
            municipis.push(data[i].municipi)
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(!found) // If not find we add into Array
    {
        array.push({
            comarca : data[i].nom_comarca,
            municipis: municipis
        })
        //municipis = [];
    }
}
```

Thanks for all really!!

Comment: I'd use a dictionary. The ket is the county and its value is an array. So you iterate your data, and you add the county to the dictionary if it doesn't exists. Then, you add an array as its value and append the municipi. In the next iterations, if the county is already in your dictionary, you simply append the municipi to the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a dictionary to keep track of duplicate nom_comarca.  Transform the municipi property into an array if the element doesn't yet exist, otherwise push the municipi value to the existing element's array.

```js
const data = [
  {"nom_comarca": "1", "municipi": "1"},
  {"nom_comarca": "1", "municipi": "2"},
  {"nom_comarca": "2", "municipi": "3"},
];

const result = Object.values(data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  if (!acc[el.nom_comarca]) {
    acc[el.nom_comarca] = {...el, municipi: [el.municipi]};
  } else {
    acc[el.nom_comarca].municipi.push(el.municipi);
  }
  return acc;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: What? You're a genius, you've solved something I've been working on for over 3 hours and thinking about how to do it.

THANK YOU SO MUCH!